# How to determine why my Android application keeps stopping?

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem with my application. The application is supposed to send a message using volume key buttons on the phone. The problem is that it keeps stopping and I do not know if it works. Here is the code, I also added some wake lock in order for my app to stay active even when phone is locked.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final static int SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 111;
private Button sendMessage;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    wl.acquire();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sendMessage = findViewById(R.id.send_message);
    final EditText phone = findViewById(R.id.phone_no);
    final EditText message = findViewById(R.id.message);
    sendMessage.setEnabled(false);


    if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        sendMessage.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String msg = message.getText().toString();
            String phonenumber = phone.getText().toString();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(msg) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(phonenumber)) {

                if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(phone), null, msg, null, null);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter a message and a phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)) {
        sendMessage.setEnabled(true);
        return true;
    } else if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)) {
        sendMessage.setEnabled(true);
        return true;
    } else
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private boolean checkPermission(String permission) {
    int checkPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
    return checkPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                sendMessage.setEnabled(true);
            }

            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "Keeps stopping".  What do you mean?  An error?

Comment: Follow [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) and Provide Error logs .

Answer (score 0):

Right now your code is not sending any messages when you press the volume key nor when you release it. You need to add this to your code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)) {
        String msg = message.getText().toString();
            String phonenumber = phone.getText().toString();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(msg) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(phonenumber)) {

                if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(phone), null, msg, null, null);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter a message and a phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
      ...
    }
```

Also, you're missing n opening bracket on the final else of your `onKeyDown()`